# Is it possible to check whether a file descriptor refers to a shared memory object?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, file-descriptor

Is it possible to check whether a file descriptor originated from a call to `shm_open()`? We already have `isatty()` that checks whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal. Is there something similar to know whether a file descriptor refers to a shared memory object?

Comment: You could get some clues from the `st_mode` and `st_rdev` members of `struct stat statbuf` after a call to `fstat(fd, &statbuf);`. I guess that `S_ISCHR(statbuf.st_mode)` would be true, and that `major(statbuf.st_rdev)` would be a specific number or within a specific range of numbers.

Comment: @IanAbbott Via `/proc/self/mountinfo` you can get the filesystem type for specific device numbers. `shm_open` is implemented as tmpfs on Linux.

Comment: A little experiment with `shm_open` and `fstat` showed that the file descriptor refers to a regular file, so ignore my earlier comment about checking `st_mode` and `st_rdev`! Interestingly, `major(statbuf.st_dev)` was 0 and `minor(statbuf.st_dev)` was non-zero.

Comment: @IanAbbott https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/devices.html?highlight=terminal Last time I've checked tmpfs did not get a unique device number; different tmpfs mounts had different ones and within the same range as NFS mounts. Therefore, you can get the file system type from mountinfo.

I'm still not sure if maybe `/dev/shm` is _required_ or _usual_ for tmpfs files created via `shm_open`...

Comment: @dyp Yes, I think you are correct. Also `major(statbuf.st_dev)` wouldn't necessarily be 0. Block major 0 is reserved for unnamed block devices, but if it runs out of minor numbers it can expand into block majors 144, 145 and 146, which allows for up to 1024 unnamed block devices.

Comment: @dyp, I think it is to be expected for POSIX implementations to have `/dev/shm` mounted as tmpfs, but not required. See: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html#NOTES

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to check whether a file descriptor originated from a call to shm_open()? We already have isatty() that checks whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal. Is there something similar to know whether a file descriptor refers to a shared memory object?

Well, `isatty()` is not a system call, but just an `ioctl(2)` wrapper call that has to be made to a tty device (one device that supports it).

but you can use `fstat(2)` with the file descriptor to get the inode information.  in the `st_mode` field of this structure there are bits that will tell you if it is a file, directory, socket, fifo, block device, char device, etc.

In you case, if you know the descriptor has been built with a call to `shm_open`, you have already answered your question.  But try `fstat(2)` to see what does it return in those bits in your `struct stat` buffer.

Beware that what `isatty(3)` does is different than what you want to know.  For `isatty(3)` to work you must pass not just a char device descriptor, but a char device that implements the ioctl call implemented in the `tty` driver, which for example will give you a `false` result when you use it with a magnetic tape descriptor.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The problem is that `struct stat` has no distinguishing property for shared memory file descriptors. Right now, I have opted for checking first whether the file descriptor is valid, then `::mmap` it, see whether that succeeds, and then see whether the mapped memory is what I expect it to be. Not ideal.

Comment: then you can try to use the `isatty()` approach: make an inocuous call, like `isatty()` does (`isatty()` uses `tcgetattr(3)` to ask for the tty configuration, and returns `false` in case it gets `ENOTTY` in `errno` variable) Just do some memory operation (attach it to the virtual memory space, for example)

Comment: IMHO a shared memory descriptor will never be used like a file descriptor, as you cannot `read()` or `write()` to it, so I cannot guess a user story in which they get mixed together and you need to try something to know if it is a shared memory or a file.  It looks to me as an instance of the X Y problem (you are trying other thing that you have not shared here)

Comment: You are probably right. What I am doing right now is share the file descriptor with child processes instead of the name of the shared memory object, so that I can immediately unlink the SHM object after creation, preventing having to deal with cleanup in case of crashes etc.